# How do you change the look of Google Custom Search search results?

Tags: adsense, google-custom-search

I'm creating a Google Custom Search results engine for my website, and it has these borders around each result, I want to change the results (styling, and html if possible). How can I do this? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You usually can't style things like this, as they're located within an `iframe` that's not hosted on your domain. I did, however, find a doc on this subject:

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/ui_xml?hl=en